# How to Implement the Server Waiting Loop(s) for Multiple Client Connections

Tags: c++, client

I'm working on a Client-Server project.  It should be able to handle multiple (>1000) client connections.

The main skeleton of my server-side waiting loop looks like this:

```
while(server->running)
{
    // If I remove this, my CPU use will be very intensive
    // but putting 10 milliseconds sleep will cause a significant delay
    // What's is the best practice?
    boost::this_thread::sleep(boost::posix_time::milliseconds(10));

    if (server->connectionQueue.empty())
        continue;

    Connection* conn = server->connectionQueue.front();
    server->connectionQueue.pop();

    Stream* stream = conn->HandleData();

    // More steps if needed here

    server->connectionQueue.push(conn);
}
```

My questions are:

1. Currently I'm using one waiting loop for all connections.  Is this correct? or what's the best practice?  Should I use a waiting loop for each connection?
2. If I remove the `thread::sleep`, my CPU use will be very intensive.  But putting 10 milliseconds sleep will cause a significant delay, especially, if there are multiple connections.  So what's is the best practice?
3. I googled, and found something called `FD_ISSET`: http://linux.die.net/man/3/fd_isset

> ```
> /* According to POSIX.1-2001 */
> #include <sys/select.h>
>
> /* According to earlier standards */
> #include <sys/time.h>
> #include <sys/types.h>
> #include <unistd.h>
>
> int select(int nfds, fd_set *readfds, fd_set *writefds,
>            fd_set *exceptfds, struct timeval *timeout);
>
> void FD_CLR(int fd, fd_set *set);
> int FD_ISSET(int fd, fd_set *set);
> void FD_SET(int fd, fd_set *set);
> void FD_ZERO(fd_set *set);
>
> #define _XOPEN_SOURCE 600
> #include <sys/select.h>
>
> int pselect(int nfds, fd_set *readfds, fd_set *writefds,
>             fd_set *exceptfds, const struct timespec *timeout,
>             const sigset_t *sigmask);
> ```

But I don't know how to use?  How can I use it for my Socket File Descriptor?

Not sure If I made myself clear.

Answer (score 1):

I would recommend you have one main loop and use `select()` to manage your connection and listening sockets.
Either `man select_tut` or visit http://beej.us/guide/bgnet/ (or both)

Comment: Hi Josh, Thanks for your reply.  I will adopt your suggestion to use one main loop and monitor (select()) all listening sockets: once one or more of them get data from the client, the connection(s) associated with the socket(s) will be active and handle the incoming data.  Is this design okay?

Comment: You can and should use select() for your connected sockets too - you can use it to handle when data can be sent/received. As a side note, make sure you account for situations where you don't send / receive all the data you expect.